# External button sending signal to app (iOS)

Tags: ios, external, hardware

I want to make an app that can receive a signal from an external button without any cables involved.

For example, I've seen apps doing this with electronic door locks. When the door gets locked/unlocked the user gets notifed via the app.

In this case, I just want an external button, and when it's pressed the user gets notifed.

I'd love any tips on what I can use, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a Bluetooth Low Energy device that will be able to notify an app of an external change. There are many chipsets, such as the TI CC2540 family which can be used as a base. You'll then need an app that is able to discover this device, connect to it, discover its services and characteristics, ask for notifications, and act upon them.

However, your question is probably way too broad for anyone to provide a precise answer.